# Ionic - AngularJS : ion-toggle doesn't update the model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a strange issue with the ion-toggle directive in Ionic framework.

When using ion-toggle like this :

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="testToggle">Test toggle</ion-toggle>
```

JS:

```
$scope.$watch('testToggle',function(value) {
    console.log('testToggle changed to '+value);
})
```

The controller doesn't receive any update at all.

Here's the CodePen :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPOMqz

You'll see that i've added an $interval that changes a binded variable to random in order to see that everything else works as expected

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 13):

I used `ng-change` to detect a change; and I am calling the function `toggleChange()` upon a change. So your `ion-toggle` will look like:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="value" ng-change="toggleChange()">Test toggle</ion-toggle>
```

And your controller will change the `$scope.value` and hence you'll get the toggle's value from `$scope.value`:

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
            $scope.value = false;
            console.log('ContactCtrl started');

            $scope.toggleChange = function() {
                if ($scope.value == false) {
                    $scope.value = true;
                } else
                    $scope.value = false;
                console.log('testToggle changed to ' + $scope.value);
            };
        }
```

Here's the Codepen for the same: http://codepen.io/keval5531/pen/LVYROp

Comment: While this works, does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Good solution, but why not use just a simpler `$scope.value = !$scope.value` in the toggleChange function?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Keval didn't work for me because he's resetting the value of the model, which puts the toggle button to its original position. So the proper answer would be to create a toggle like the following.

`<ion-toggle ng-model=value ng-change="toggleChange()">Test toggle</ion-toggle>`

And then write the controller as follows.

```
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
        $scope.value = false;

        $scope.toggleChange = function() {
            console.log('testToggle changed to ' + $scope.value);
        };
    }
```